# how to use uploadfile that posted by jquery

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have an FileUpload in my page.how can I post the selected file by this FileUpload to the host path by JQuery? I found this code in internet:

HTML

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
<div id="response"></div>
```

JS

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){

        var input = document.getElementById("file");
        var formdata = false;
        if (window.FormData) {
            formdata = new FormData();
        }
        input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {

            var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

            for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
                file = this.files[i];

                if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                    if ( window.FileReader ) {
                        reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                            //showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }

                    if (formdata) {
                        formdata.append("image", file);
                        formdata.append("extra",'extra-data');
                    }

                    if (formdata) {
                        jQuery('div#response').html('<br /><img src="ajax-loader.gif"/>');


                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "upload.aspx/Upload",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: formdata,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function (res) {
                             jQuery('div#response').html("Successfully uploaded");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Not a vaild image!');
                }   
            }

        }, false);

    });
```

The writer has wrote that"At the code level this will work as normal file upload" but I couldn't understand how.is there anybody who knows it?

Comment: This is a simple and easy approach to upload the contents on a remote Url.In the above code an ajax call is made to the remote uploading url and the data is passed to it. on successful response, it updates the text on the response div. appropriate file loader class is used for loading the data into a variable before passing it to remote URL for uploading in ajax call. i hope that clears your doubt

Comment: thanks for your response.I know how it works.I dont know how to get upload file in my asp.net codes.in other post case I saw before we post data in this format:(data:"{ID:2}") and we get it in code side in this format: [WebMethod]
    public static String Upload(Int64 ID)
    {}   , but it is deferent from it.how can I use the posted uploadfile in my code side?

Comment: ok, the format like this `data:"{ID:2}")`,refers to key - value pair just like a associative array.this way it is done, so that its easy to retrieve corresponding value at the receivers end. whatever format we use while sending same format need to maintained at the receivers side as wel.

Comment: do I have to add the parameter to my function in code side?can you write an example for my case I wrote in my ask? thanks in advanced

Comment: i guess the code used for receiving the ajax request is fine except the parameter should be a string, since we are passing a string data.`[WebMethod()]
public static string Test(string data)
{
   string ret;
  // process the data received from ajax request via "data"
  return ret ;
}`

Comment: but what we pass is an Fileupload as I write in my ask

Comment: Actually in the above code if you see, the FileReader class has a function called "readAsDataURL(file)", which will read the File/blob's data  and encode as a data URL. so i suppose you need to capture the same in your Receivers side code with appropriate datatype.I`m dont have much idea about asp.net,i guess u need to search on net,on how to handle "URL data" at receivers side.

Answer (score 0):

To send that into a WebMethod, you'd still need to send the Base64 string in as JSON and you'd need to set the contentType correctly to `application/json`. I believe ASP.NET will simply ignore your request to upload.aspx/Upload otherwise.

Alternatively, it might be more straightforward to POST that file into an HttpHandler of your own, so you can get access to the POST data closer to the metal.

Comment: thanks for your response.Could you please give me a full example of upload a file by jquery.I need to solve this problem imidiataly.Thanks in advanced

Comment: I don't have a full example handy. You should find lots of example code if you search for something like "jQuery file upload to ASP.NET" though.